# How to Include "<" in the string in PHP

Tags: php

My PHP string has < in its value which is omitting the characters after it, How should I do that

```
    <?php 
$abc = escapeshellarg("Amp^[dfdf&c4hcSdf/Z<dfdrV");

    echo $abc; // output is Amp^[dfdf&c4hcSdf/Z
    // Desired Output is Amp^[dfdf&c4hcSdf/Z<dfdrV
    ?>
```

Please help me to understand this

Thank You

Comment: `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 1):

The `<` *is* included, but your browser thinks it's part of an HTML tag, so hides it. Look at "View Source".

You need to *escape* it, so that it becomes `&lt;` which will *look like* `<` when displayed in the browser.

You possibly realised this, but grabbed at the wrong function - escaping isn't something you can do "once and for all", it has to be specific to the context where you're using something. [escapeshellarg](https://php.net/escapeshellarg) is for escaping strings used in command-line ("shell") commands. The function for escaping for use in HTML is called [htmlspecialchars](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars).